# Prove that $[T]_{B_1}^{B_1}$ = $[I]_{B_1}^{B_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $B_1 = \{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ and $B_2 = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be ordered bases of the vector space $V$. Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be the linear operator defined by $Tu_1 = v_1, Tu_2 = v_2, \dots,  T_{u_{n}} = v_n$. Prove that $[T]_{B_1}^{B_1} = [I]_{B_1}^{B_2}$. Hint: Compare the matrices column by column

So this is the problem basically, I really got no clue, I tried a theorem I knew which was
$[T]_{B_1}^{B_1} = [I]_{B_1}^{B_2}[T]_{B_2}^{B_2} [I]_{B_2}^{B_1}$, except I tried manipulating it and I didn't find the solution. I tried to do it based on the hint, I really couldn't get far since I didn't really understand 100%, for me this is $[I]_{B_1}^{B_2}$

[image: Matrix of <span class=]$[I]_{B_1}^{B_2}$" />

but I got no clue the matrix of $[T]_{B_1}^{B_1}$ and even when I got it how do I compare it, sorry I'm kinda lost on this problem, I'm usually not this lost, linear algebra is a tuff one for me

Comment: Please explain your notation. What are $1^B$, $1$, $2^B$ and $2$?

Comment: It's the change of basis matrix, from B1 to B2, and viceversa, looks scuffed I know. I didn't really knew how to put the superindex and subindex together since B had a subindex too (1,2)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if $A = \{a_1, a_2,\dots,a_m\}$ and $B = \{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ then

$$[T]^A_B = \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  \\ [Ta_1]_B & [Ta_2]_B &\cdots&[Ta_m]_B \\ \\ \end{array}\right].$$

Or maybe you have defined $[T]^A_B$ as the matrix such that $[T]^A_B [x]_A = [Tx]_B$, in which case the above is a theorem.

Anyways, you don't have to think, just calmly replace $A, B, T, m, n$ with what is given.

\begin{align*}
[I]^{B_2}_{B_1} &= \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  \\ [Iv_1]_{B_1} & [Iv_2]_{B_1} &\cdots&[Iv_n]_{B_1} \\ \\ \end{array}\right] \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  \\ [v_1]_{B_1} & [v_2]_{B_1} &\cdots&[v_n]_{B_1} \\ \\ \end{array}\right]. \\
[T]_{B_1}^{B_1} &= \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  \\ [Tu_1]_{B_1} & [Tu_2]_{B_1} &\cdots&[Tu_n]_{B_1} \\ \\ \end{array}\right] \\
&= \left[\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}  \\ [v_1]_{B_1} & [v_2]_{B_1} &\cdots&[v_n]_{B_1} \\ \\ \end{array}\right].
\end{align*}

Or, you can do this using the $[T]^A_B [x]_A = [Tx]_B$ definition:

\begin{align*}
[T]^{B_1}_{B_1} [u_i]_{B_1} &= [Tu_i]_{B_1} = [v_i]_{B_1}, \\
[I]^{B_2}_{B_1} [v_i]_{B_2} &= [Iv_i]_{B_1} = [v_i]_{B_1}.
\end{align*}

Note that $[u_i]_{B_1} = [v_i]_{B_2} = e_i$, the $i$-th column of the identity matrix. So the two matrices $[T]^{B_1}_{B_1}$ and $[I]^{B_2}_{B_1}$ agree on a basis (the standard basis) and hence they must be equal.

Comment: Oh I see,  we did touch in class [T]AB[x]A=[Tx]B , I even used it a couple hours ago for a solution, thanks for the feedback, you make it sound easy